# EACCES Error on Startup

Tags: visual-studio-code

Since upgrading to VSCode 1.5.1 (from 1.4), I get an error message saying "connect EACCES 191.238.172.191:443" whenever starting VSCode. I've turned off the various documented privacy settings and blocked VSCode in my firewall (because my internet is usually slow and expensive). That URL seems to point to Microsoft, Brazil. Is there any way to stop VSCode 1.5.1 from trying to phone home?

Comment: Found some github's issues that could be useful https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7706 https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5596

Comment: Thanks; I knew about those. My issue is that I'd like VS Code to stop trying to access that site when I don't want it to, not that I'd like it to succeed.

Comment: @PeterMcLennan exactly the same here. Did you find the way how to stop VS trying access that site?

Comment: @SonnyD No. MS acknowledged the issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11837 and applied a fix to suppress the message, but they refused to stop the attempted internet access. It doesn't seem to have been rolled out in VSCode 1.5.2, but I guess it's not seen as critical.

Comment: Thanks a lot for response. Suppress the error will fully satisfying me, don't need anything more.  There is nothing else just wait.

Answer (score 3):

1.  code --verbose

[main 2020-03-18T15:26:02.655Z] Error: connect EACCES /Users/nasa/Library/Application Support/Code/1.43.0-main.sock
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1056:14)
[main 2020-03-18T15:26:02.657Z] Lifecycle#kill()

2.  cd ~/Library/ApplicationSupport/code
3.  sudo chmod -R 777 1.43.0-main.sock

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for.