# Visual Studio Code not working on MacOS MOJAVE

Tags: visual-studio-code

After installing MacOS Mojave, Visual Studio Code is not working. Here is the error:

```
~$ code --verbose
[main 12:07:21 PM] Error: connect EACCES /Users/joedoe/Library/Application Support/Code/1.27.2-main.sock
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)
[main 12:07:21 PM] Lifecycle#kill()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39421755/1531971

Comment: met the same issue, not yet found any solutions. I tried to reinstall vscode.